# change ampersand character used by \url

Tags: fonts, urls, ampersand

For normal text, I replaced the ampersand symbol with some thing different, specifically a scaled ampersand taken from a different font (because reasons). Perhaps the less lazy method would have been to create a virtual font for this purpose, but simply redefining the `\&` macro worked fine - until I started using the `url` package. How can I make `\url` use my customized `\&` for the ampersand symbol?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

% Redefine \&:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\ampersand\&
% for the sake of this MWE:
\def\&{\scalebox{0.7}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\ampersand}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text: & Foobar \& Cie.\\
Bad url: & \url{https://example.com/page?x=1&y=2}\\
Manual fix: & \url{https://example.com/page?x=1}\&y=2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples; it is not meant for them, but for testing package option loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the conversion to the internal lists of `url`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\Url@OTnonTT{\do\&{\&}}
\makeatother

% Redefine \&:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\ampersand\&
% for the sake of this MWE:
\def\&{\scalebox{0.7}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\ampersand}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text: & Foobar \& Cie.\\
Bad url: & \url{https://example.com/page?x=1&y=2}\\
Manual fix: & \url{https://example.com/page?x=1}\&y=2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]